# Status 400 error, `Illegal character in fragment at index` when using NuGet v3 API

Tags: nuget, artifactory

I'm facing a HTTP Status 400 error when trying to access a NuGet repo in Artifactory using api V3:

Url: `https://<artifactory-url>/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/<nuget-repo>/query?q=&skip=0&take=26&prerelease=false&supportedFramework=.NETStandard,Version=v2.0&supportedFramework=.NETFramework,Version=v4.8&semVerLevel=2.0.0`

Result:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 400,
    "message" : "Illegal character in fragment at index 44: svn://<server>/trunk1/C#-Software/Hardware related/Equipment/<project>/trunk"
  } ]
}
```

The mentioned svn path is part of the metadata of a .nupkg package. I assume, the hashtag or a slash is the problem.

The Artifactory URL was created by Visual Studio, but the same error occurs using the CLI:
`nuget search <packageName> -Source Artifactory`

Using the v2 api works, in nuget CLI and VS.

I can't change the meta description of old packages, they aren't owned by me.

Any advice?

Thanks!